# Loop through html tags in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to build a table with Angular2 that has 48 rows and I want to do that with a ngFor. For now I do it by going through an array (size 48), but I think its pretty inefficient and not a good programming style. 
Is there an elegant way for doing loops of  html-tags in Angular2? Is there something like a normal for where I can set start and end?

In the Component I have this Array:

```
private rows = new Array(48);
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr *ngFor="#row of rows ; #i = index">
    <td>{{i}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Any more concrete information about the use case where this might be useful?

Comment: you want to bind length of `*ngFor` ? start and end point ?

Comment: I want a loop with start and endpoint without using an array

Comment: yes i have a trick on HTML with *ngFor where you can use start ans end point but you have to use array for the same if you need same ill post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in the comment questioner wants to use `*ngFor` in the HTML but by  defining some start point and end point. so there is not exactly same property exist for the *ngFor as officials but yes we can do the same with this trick. ill assume one demo example modifie this as per your need.

```
<ul>
  <div *ngFor="#a of abc">
  <li *ngIf='a<6'>
    <span >{{a}}</span>
  </li>
  </div>
</ul>

abc = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

so by doing so we can bind start and end point.

working [plunkr example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/789Hjwur8fd15OIqoY8H?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

Nope, there is only `ngFor`. It's quite unusual IMHO to build HTML in a loop that's doesn't directly depend on any concrete data the rows are built for.

Comment: I want to build a week table with 7 colums and 48 rows. What do you suggest to speed up my table?

Comment: Use static HTML, alternatively you can also create a string in a TypeScript for loop and add it using `[innerHtml]="someGeneratedHtml"`

Comment: Ok I will do that! Thank you

Comment: I have changed the code now, but I have a problem: inside the <td> i have a link with an angular (click) function. The problem is that angular is not interpreted inside innerHtml...What should I do?

Comment: Use `ngFor` or static HTML. Why do you need to generate it dynamically when a bit copy paste (static HTML approach) will lead to a much more efficient solution?

Comment: Yes I think I have no other choice than hardcoding everything, because if I would use ngFor I would be at the startpoint again